# AngularJS factory undefined error

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck here, I don't know what I am missing or how to debug this further.  I continue to get this error: 'updateMemberServiceFactory is undefined' when I call it from an ng-click event.  Please advise. If this is a simple typo I apologize I just can't see what's wrong.  I'm trying to call into a PUT method on my controller but it never gets called.  New to AngularJS.  Thank you.

```
securityApp.factory('updateMemberServiceFactory', function ($http) {

    function update(memberServiceID) {

        $http({ method: 'PUT', url: 'http://localhost:62791/api/MemberServices/', data: { memberServiceID: memberServiceID } })
            .then(function (result) {
                alert('success');
            }, function (errorResponse) {

        });
    };

});

securityApp.controller('memberServicesController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, getTokenFromServer, updateMemberServiceFactory) {

    var id = $routeParams.memberID;

    $scope.username = 'aharris1@test.com';
    $scope.password = 'SuperPass1!';

    getTokenFromServer.getToken($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function (data) {
        $scope.token = data;

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/MemberServices/' + id + '?access_token=' + $scope.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.token } })
            .success(function (response) {

                $scope.memberServices = "";
                $scope.memberServices = response;

                $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Members/' + id + '?access_token=' + $scope.token, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.token } })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.member = response;
                    });

                $http.get('/api/ServiceTypes/')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.serviceTypes = response.data;
                    });
            });
    });

    $scope.updateMemberService = function () {        
        updateMemberServiceFactory.update( { memberServiceID: memberServiceID }, null, function () {
            alert('update called');
        });
    };

});
```

---

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none;" ng-click="updateMemberService(memberService.memberServiceID)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
```

Comment: "Error: updateMemberServiceFactory is undefined
$scope.updateMemberService@http://localhost:62791/Scripts/app/Security.js:357:9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `someApp.factory(someFunction)` the some `someFunction` should return an object that will be injected when needed.

In your case:

```
securityApp.factory('updateMemberServiceFactory', function ($http) {

    function update(memberServiceID) {

        $http({ method: 'PUT', url: 'http://localhost:62791/api/MemberServices/', data: { memberServiceID: memberServiceID } })
            .then(function (result) {
                alert('success');
            }, function (errorResponse) {

        });
    };

    return { // <---- this object will get injected, when required
         update : update
    }

});
```